# cross browser indent for second line in ordered list with inside position - impossible?

Tags: html, css

I've been reading threads here for a few hours and couldn't find a solution.

I want to create an ordered list, with theses requirements:

1. need to be with inside position effect, so there's no big margin from bullet to text.
2. second line must be indented so it would be aligned with the text..
3. must work the same way on all browsers, from IE7 and above.

A. this solution works well only on chrome (in FF and IE there are deviations, css reset didn't help):

```
<ol type="1" style="list-style-position:inside; margin:0px; padding-left:15px;">
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>Text</li>
        <li  style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
    text-indent: -1em; margin-left: 1em;">longer Text, longer Text, longer Text, longer Text<br>
second line of longer Text</li>
</ol>
```

B. this solution does not work on IE7, the bullets disappear (no deviations though):

http://jsfiddle.net/4rnNK/1/

Thanks

Comment: I would be happy with a partial IE7 support ;-)

Comment: use text-indent in css targeting li

Comment: @AbelRaj I'm not sure what you mean, can you explain

Comment: I tried to understand what you needed and given a simple solution. check this fiddle. look for the first list item. is that what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/4rnNK/155/

Comment: there's a bigger margin between 1 and the text in comparison to other numbers; also would it work on IE7?

Comment: you can define the margin from bullet to text by setting the padding on the ordered list element, that way you can use outside position effect

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late a little, but here is a solution:

CSS:

```
    ol,li {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    ol {
      padding-left: 30px;
    }

    li {
      margin: 0 0 15px -5px;
    }

    li span {
      position: relative;
      left: -10px;
    }
```

and HTML:

```
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet fugit error quae unde omnis aut aut, eos ut ratione omnis laudantium ab sit architecto nemo perspiciatis quasi doloremque voluptatem sunt ipsam ratione aperiam aperiam, aperiam error beatae voluptas aut doloremque eaque sit ut inventore ut omnis omnis, 
</p>

<ol>
  <li>
    <span>
      omnis ab quasi voluptatem voluptatem consequuntur sed fugit beatae veritatis sed quae dolores iste quasi ipsam ipsam, perspiciatis sed inventore eaque totam inventore sed ut sit dolores perspiciatis inventore ipsa totam ipsam ipsam, 
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>
      omnis ab quasi voluptatem voluptatem consequuntur sed fugit beatae veritatis sed quae dolores iste quasi ipsam ipsam, perspiciatis sed inventore eaque totam inventore sed ut sit dolores perspiciatis inventore ipsa totam ipsam ipsam, 
    </span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Here is a fiddle to show the result: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MaxCloutier/4rnNK/421/)

Answer (score 0):

(This is based on AbelRaj's comment but cleaner.) Roll your own using css `counter` and wrap it in li::before.

http://jsfiddle.net/4rnNK/1463/